# Standard way to embed version information into a Lua script?

Tags: lua

Python has the `__version__` variable as a way for scripts to hold version information. Does Lua have a similar standard?

Answer (score 2):

As an embedded scripting language, Lua generally [provides mechanisms, not policy](http://lua-users.org/wiki/MechanismNotPolicy). So there aren't standardized ways of doing a lot things in Lua.

Including script versioning.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the `_VERSION` variable:

```
print(_VERSION) --> lua 5.3
```

Comment: It is a version of a lua, not the script.